# React: 404 Found when importing local images

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, webpack

I am having trouble having an image show up on my personal website. I am using React to display each page on my site. On my AboutMe Page, I have successfully imported an image and have displayed it correctly, where Webpack had no problem building and finding the image. As you can see below, this is what I wrote:

`import img from '../../../public/assets/images/linked-in-profile.jpg'`

```
<Col>
   <img className="about-image" src={img} />
</Col>
```

However, on my Projects page, I am trying to have Bootstrap cards that contain images. I followed the same steps that I did on my AboutMe page; I imported the image and added my  tag inside my card. When I check my site running on a localhost, the image does not show, and my console reports an error with ":8080/public/Floor-Is-Lava.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:8080/public/Floor-Is-Lava.jpg 404 (Not Found)"

The code on this page is:

```
import img from '../../../public/floor-is-lava.jpg'
```

```
<Card bg="light" text="secondary" style={{ width: '350px', height: '300px' }}>
   <img className="project-img" src={img} />
   <Card.ImgOverlay>
      <Card.Text>Go to github</Card.Text>
   </Card.ImgOverlay>
</Card>
```

The error directs to this snippet of code in my server/index.js:

```
 // any remaining requests with an extension (.js, .css, etc.) send 404
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (path.extname(req.path).length) {
      const err = new Error('Not found')
      err.status = 404
      next(err)
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })
```

My Webpack says that all my images were successfully built, but I have no clue why only one shows up on my site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you are referencing public directory images.
Copy your image to src directory and import it. then it might work.

```
import img from '../../floor-is-lava.jpg'

<Card bg="light" text="secondary" style={{ width: '350px', height: '300px' }}>
   <img className="project-img" src={img} />
   <Card.ImgOverlay>
      <Card.Text>Go to github</Card.Text>
   </Card.ImgOverlay>
</Card>
```

Please let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help! so i made a directory outside of public named src. I added my assets/images directory into src. Just like before, my about me picture works, but I get a 404 (not found) for my project card...

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem with my React App that I built using Webpack config 4x.
I spent a few hours but eventually got this working now.

1. Created a folder named assets/images under /src
2. Copied my image to the above folder
3. If you haven't npm i url-loader
4. In my webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {

  entry: SRC_DIR + '/app/',
  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR + "/build",
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3333,
    contentBase: DIST_DIR + "/build",
    inline: true
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(js|jsx|png|jpg|svg|gif|ico)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
          }
        }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: 'css-loader'
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

In my component file:

```
import imageToRender from '../../assets/images/some.jpg';

...
...

<div>
   <img src={imageToRender}/>
</div>
```